# Line above page numbering for even and odd pages

Tags: header-footer, positioning, fancyhdr, rules, books

my problem is simple. With the following code I have the line above the page numbering only for even pages. Also For some pages, for e.g. the contents in the header I have for the right and the left side both the name of the chapter (contents in this case), as in figure: [image]. In this page, because is even, I have the line above the page numbering.

this is the code:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage,oneside,openright]{book}
    \linespread{1.5}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    %\usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    %\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
    \usepackage[write]{frontespizio}
    \usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} 
    \usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
    \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
    \setlength\footnotemargin{10pt}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
    
    \usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}%
\newpagestyle{ruled}{%
\headrule
\sethead{}{}{\ifthechapter{\thechapter }{}\itshape\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}}
\footrule
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}
\pagestyle{ruled}
    
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\footrule
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

 \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
    \begin{document}
   

    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \chapter*{Acknowledgements}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Acknowledgements}%
\lipsum[1-4]

\clearpage
    \tableofcontents
    
    \mainmatter 
    \clearpage
    \chapter{Background}
    \label{Background}
\lipsum[1-5]
    \cleardoublepage
    
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}References}%
    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
    {\footnotesize
    \bibliography{mybib}}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: It's not clear for me what is your question.

Comment: @manooooh I Have the line above the number of the page only for even page, and not for odd pages. I want the line for each pages odds and evens. Second I want to remove the left part of the head above the line, because is repeated!

Comment: Do you really need a header on the first page of the chapter, to remind you its title, just in case you didn't see the heading?

Comment: @Bernard no, but I don't know how to remove the name of the chapter in the page when init the chapter

Comment: The standard classes use the `plain`style for the first page of chapters, so you only have the page number in the footer. You might try to redefine the plain style to add  a footer  rule.

Comment: @Bernard, which style do you suggest to use?

Comment: @Bernard, does the style resolve also the problem with the duplicate name of the chapter?

Comment: With the plain style , there is normally no header.

Comment: @Bernard, How can I remove the chapter name for the \tableofcontents?

Comment: @Bernard, can you write me a footer rule? I have the line only for the even pages

Comment: I can try, but usually, I do this sort of things with `titleps` (a package which comes with `titlesec`), not with fancyhdr.

Comment: Ok, maybe you can translate the code from fancyhdr to titleps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `titleps` in the place of `fancyhdr`. Note that we have to use the `\chaptermark` command for unnumbered chapters:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage,oneside,openright]{book}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[write]{frontespizio}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength\footnotemargin{10pt}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\usepackage{titleps}%
\newpagestyle{ruled}{%
\headrule
\sethead{}{}{\itshape\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}}
\footrule
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}
\pagestyle{ruled}

\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\footrule
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\chaptermark{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Acknowledgements}%
\lipsum[1-5]

\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\clearpage
\chapter{Background}
\label{Background}
\lipsum
\cleardoublepage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}References}%
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
{\footnotesize
\bibliography{mybib}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit* To add the chapter number in the header (for numbered chapters) you have to load `\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}` in the place of `\usepackage{titleps}`, and  use

```
\sethead{}{}{\ifthechapter{\thechapter }{}\itshape\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but now the chapter background has the name "chapter 1" instead I want only the number 1. If I use \chaptermark{Background} I have no "chapter" before the Title background but I have no also the number. How can I solve?

Comment: @Will: Please see my edit. There are a couple of lines to change.

Comment: I saw also the editing, but I can see any changing expect of a line \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}. I added this line also before even if it was not in the as a code line. Don't change anything

Comment: @Will: I don't know what happened. Everything had disappeared. I've edited again. The code provides the chapter number in upshape, and the chapter title in italic, because I think it looks better, but it's very simple to change that to fit your taste.

Comment: Sorry, but substituting \usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec} instead of \usepackage{titleps} and the last 1setthead instead of the previous one (between \headrule and \footrule), it returns me an error on \pagestyle{ruled}: ! Undefined control sequence.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo: it is  `\sethead`, not `\setthead`. If it doesn't work with this modification, could you post a short code reproducing the problem?

Comment: ok, it does't work unfortunately, they give no error but remain with the Chapter 1 before the name. I should post on another question? Or in this one?

Comment: It is as simple to edit this post. Don't forget to add a small example code.

Comment: I edited the post, I also tried it, so you can just copy and paste, I added also all the ipsum

Comment: Sorry, I solved adding just \titleformat{\chapter}[display] %toglie il chap da ogni capitolo
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}. Very last question, how can I put in the header 1 - Backgounrd, because in this way the number has just one space before the name, I adding the - but the results is not very beautiful

Comment: I was just thinking maybe the code worked completely using \chapterformat, but you found before I did. For the other problem, did you notice the code has a space just after `\thechapter` ?.  To be sure it's no lost, I suggest adding a fullstup and an `\enspace`, like this: `\sethead{}{}{\ifthechapter{\thechapter.\enspace}{}...`.

Comment: Ok, now it works, is in the form "1.    Background"; there is a way to put a "-" instead o a dot? Because if I just substitute "-" with "." it returns "1-     Backgound". I want like: "1  -  Backgound". Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not sure I understand (what you want is broken over two lines).  You indeed can replace the dot with a dash (preferably an endash, not a hyphen) and add thin unbreakable spaces (`\,`) on each side. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Yes I want just to change the format of the header in each page in the forma number - name instead of using number. name, not in 2 lines just in one

Comment: Then do as I said: `\sethead{}{}{\ifthechapter{\thechapter\,--\,}{}\itshape\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}}`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot it works !

Comment: Glad to have been helpful!

Comment: Hi, I used this line to remove the name "chap" from each chapter: `\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}`, but now I just have the name of the chapter without the number, how can I add in this line the number of each chapter? So for e.g. 1 Background? thanks

Comment: The second argument should no be empty.  Use something like `\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\normalfont\bfseries\Huge}{thechapter}{2ex}{}` if you want the chapter number with the same font size.

Comment: Thanks it works, but using \thechapter with a \. But now the chapter is divided in two lines: number and in the line below the name. How can I add to make them together?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I thought you wanted so, since you used the `display` style. For what you want, use the `block` style instead, and add `\filcenter` in the first mandatory argument if you want the whole block to be centred.

Comment: I solved using `\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\huge}{\thechapter.}{18pt}{\huge}`

Comment: Yes, `hang` is the default style and it also works, as long as you don't want to centre the number+title block.